# How to loop an array on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

I've been trying to make a script to change the text of a span.

Admittedly I'm not fantastic with jQuery and have found a script. I've edited i but i cannot get the script to loop and i don't know where to even start. Any code hints or links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the jQuery so far:

```
function change() {
        $('#msg').html(options.pop()).fadeIn(750).delay(2000).fadeOut(750, change);
};

var options = [
    "Red Bull",
    "Smoke",
    "Babes",
    "css",
    "batman"
].reverse(); 
change();
```

And on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5s8y3/214/

Comment: Your fiddle is appear to be working. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @BasitSaeed, it's not looping.  It just cycles once.

Comment: @BasitSaeed It stops on the last variable of the array :<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop popping off the array and use an iterator instead.

```js
var messages = ["Red Bull", "Smoke", "Babes", "css", "batman"],
    i = 0;

(function change() {
    var msg = messages[i > messages.length - 1 ? (i = 0) : i++];
    $("#msg").html(msg).fadeIn(750).delay(2000).fadeOut(750, change);
})();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5s8y3/218/)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that syntax.  Nice (I think).

Comment: It's just a named IIFE and a ternary, no magic, but it might seem a little "strange" at first ?

Comment: True.  Here's an option if you want to randomize it http://jsfiddle.net/5s8y3/221/

Comment: I guess it seems strange because it's not obvious that `i=0 : i++` are returning `i`, not just setting it.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a global variable:

```js
var i = 0;
```

Now, add this to your `change()` function:

```js
if (i < messages.length) {
    i++;
} else {
    i = 0;
}
```

This portion of code, will loop over your array and go back to the beginning when it has reached the end.

Then, change `messages.pop()` to `messages[i]`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s8y3/220/).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `Array.pop` removes the element from the array, so once it's gone through your list of messages once there's no more entries and it starts throwing errors. To get it to loop continuously, add the newly removed message to the front of the array:

```
function change() {
    var message = messages.pop();
    messages.unshift(messages);
    $('#msg').html(message).fadeIn(750).delay(2000).fadeOut(750, change);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

pop() will remove the value from array. So, it works for one full cycle. After that array is empty. So, it  displays blank value. actually it works in loop.

```
var messages = [
    "Red Bull",
    "Smoke",
    "Babes",
    "css",
    "batman"
].reverse();

var i = messages.length;
function change() {
        i=(i%messages.length);
        $('#msg').html(messages[i++]).fadeIn(750).delay(2000).fadeOut(750, change);

};
```